# Nature of sub sequences when limit infimum or supremum exist

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Assume we have a sequence $ a_n $ such that any one of $ \lim inf $ or $ \lim sup $ exist. Let’s say $ \lim inf =l $ exist( this can be $\lim sup$ also .Then we know that at least one subsequence converges to $ l$ . But what I am proposing is that every subsequence either converges or tends to infinity .

No subsequence can oscillate randomly and be bounded . Since if even one such subsequence exist then $ \lim inf $ or $ \lim sup $  cannot be uniquely determined .

Am I right ?

Comment: No. $a_n = (-1)^n$ is a counterexample.

Comment: Both subsequences converge one to -1 another to 1

Comment: Note that $a_n$ is a subsequence of itself. Or consider the subsequence $a_{3n}$, which oscillates as well.

Comment: Ohh yeah understood thx